# changing position of menu and arrow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using this exact example on Codepen: https://codepen.io/Aislam23/pen/aKveGp as my menu button.

Now I am trying to figure out, how to show the arrow first and when clicked the menu button.
In the Codepen you have the burger menu icon first then the arrow, I want it the opposite way.

Is it even possible ?

```js
$('.menu-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  $(this).toggleClass('menu-btn_active');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
.section {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #7b1fa2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.menu-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
.menu-btn span,
.menu-btn span::before,
.menu-btn span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; margin-top: -1px;
  left: 50%; margin-left: -10px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #222;
}
.menu-btn span::before,
.menu-btn span::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.menu-btn span::before {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}
.menu-btn span::after {
  transform: translateY(5px);
}

.menu-btn_active span:before {
  transform: rotate(-35deg);
  width: 10px;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}
.menu-btn_active span:after {
  transform: rotate(35deg);
  width: 10px;
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.menu-block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.menu-nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  
}
.menu-nav__link {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.menu-nav__link {
  transition: 0.5s;
  transform-origin: right center;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu-nav__link_active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <a href="#" class="menu-btn">
    <span></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can simply start with class="menu-btn_active" in your html. If you actually want to *understand* what the css is doing, you would need to reverse the styles between menu-btn and menu-btn_active to see which styles are contributing to drawing the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done easily by adding the menu-btn_active class to the a.href.

```
<div class="section">
  <a href="#" class="menu-btn menu-btn_active">
    <span></span>
  </a>
</div>
```